# Check value of neighbouring squares in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, 2d

I am creating a simple mine-sweeper board with 2D array. I wants to populate the squares surrounding the "Bomb(s)" with respective numbers. 
I don't need to care whether the board I created can be solved. (Not important here)

My question is: How can we populate the numbers elegantly without listing out all the possibilities as if we were hard-coding?

What I came out with for now is a massive nested if-statements to check whether the neighbour is

```
 -Inside bounds of array
 -Is it a bomb
 -Is it empty
 -Is it already a number
```

It looks awfully long and hard-coded.

Is there a simple and elegant way to check the values of the neighbours in a 2D Matrix?

I realize there is similar question in SO asking in Python language, the solutions there were very "pythonic". I am looking for a simple approach by just using simple structure like (loops, if-statement, etc.) on a simple 2D array.

Just imagine this task is given to a new student in programming who only knows the fundamentals like if-statements and loops. So suggested solutions with lambda, recursive, iterators, etc. should be avoided.

Comment: Can you not just iterate over the bombs and increment a counter in the 8 cells surrounding each bomb? Of course you still need to do proper bound checking so that you don't try to access non-existing cells.

Comment: @mhj That's my point. But how do you do it without listing all possibilities? Currently I am listing out all directions - NW, N, NE, W, E, SW, S, SE. A long nested if solution which I am looking for ways to replace it with just a loop or something simple.

Comment: Well I assume you know the x and y indexes of the positions of the bombs in your 2D array. So finding their neighboring 8 cells is just a matter of accessing index[x-1][y-1] (NW), index[x][y-1] (N), index[x+1][y-1] (NE), index[x-1][y] (W), and so on. You only have to do this once for each bomb, so there's no need to iterate over the entire grid.

Comment: @Mhj Sry if I didn't specify my ques clearly. Currently I am already just checking the neighbours of the bombs. But I am looking for ways to simplify the algorithm of neighbour checking.

Comment: I think I would suggest a different approach. Start with an empty board - every entry is 0. Then iterate over the number of bombs you want to place - for each bomb, pick a random location, check for a collision and repick until you have a spot that didn't have a bomb before. Then put a "bomb" value in that cell and increment the counts in the (up to) eight neighbors that aren't bombs. That's probably more straightforward than trying a post-processing step. Also, put an 8x8 grid in the center of a 10x10 array to avoid boundary complications...

Comment: Nevermind, I came out with a dynamic solution already. Just use a simple nested for-loop. It automatically cycle through all the neighbours nicely. I don't understand why some people use convoluted solution like lamda & iterators to such simple task.

Comment: I tremendously optimized my big mass of nested-if from 88 lines to just 10 lines. Working dynamically. I feel great.

Answer (score 1):

A main cause of complexity when checking neighbors is the boundaries.  If you're in a cell in the first row, for example, you don't want to check the three neighbors above because they would be outside the array.

There are several common ways of eliminating the boundary checking.  Let's assume you have a class with an interface like this:

```
class Board {
  public:
    bool IsBomb(int row, int col) const;
    int GetCount(int row, int col) const;
    ...
};
```

You can hide the boundary checking in the implementation of the `IsBomb` method.  For example, if you call `IsBomb` with coordinates that are outside the playfield, it should return `false` rather than actually looking in the array (or whatever your storage mechanism is).  Now `GetCount` can simply call IsBomb for all eight neighbors without worrying about whether any of those neighbors is off the edge of the playfield.  This is the data abstraction approach.

Another approach is to make the board bigger on all sides, but only loop through the inner squares.  Then you don't need to check if the neighboring squares are in bounds or not.  This would be an implementation detail that you hide in the methods of Board.  It's completely compatible with first approach.

There are other hacks for avoiding boundary checks in loops, like dividing the board into nine special cases (corners, edges, and middle), but that would be overkill for a minesweeper like game.  And it doesn't reduce complexity; that would mostly be for performance in some extreme case.

Comment: I came out with a very simple yet dynamic solution for checking bounds all in 1 short line of code. But this is done after 4 hours of thinking. I don't even need to call any function to make it look elegant. My codes are only 3-5 lines actually. I am just surprised until now, no one in SO is able to provide that simple solution even though similar ques has been asked in SO years ago.

Comment: @user3437460: Please share your solution in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x =0; x<numRows; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y<numCols; y++){
        if(array[x][y] != "bomb"){
             array[x][y] = number
        }
    }
}
```

Best way to do this is just by cycling through each index and checking if theres a bomb. If there isn't you add a number. The first for loop goes through each row, then the next for loop goes through each column. So you would check row 1 versus column 1, column2, column3, etc. Then once row 1 is completed move onto row 2 and check versus column1, column2, etc. until every position has been searched.

Comment: This is not checking the neighbour... this is just looping through whether every single array element is a "bomb" or not.

Comment: So what you want then is once you are at a specific index check all of the neighbors surrounding just that index?

Comment: Yes. Checking all neighbours of specific index.